# eslint rule to force space between ) and {

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there any [eslint rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/) to force space between `)` and `{`?

### Invalid

```
if (true){
  ...
}

function doSomething(){
  ...
}
```

### Valid

```
if (true) {
  ...
}

function doSomething() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: You already linked to the rules. Were you really not able to read / search them yourself?

Comment: Not sure how I missed that when I ran through each of them after ⌘ + F + `space`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[space-before-blocks](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-before-blocks) rule does that.

Comment: Thank you @gp, not sure how I missed that when I ran through each of them after ⌘ + F + `space`.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow hey-we-read-the-manual-for-you service.